# Html message with <br> not working in a simple angular material Toaster

Tags: angularjs, angular-toastr

I need to use Angular Material toaster in every page of my project and the message may contain html tags. But the html message is not working with Angular Material toaster.

```
$mdToast.show(
    $mdToast.simple()
       .textContent('Field is required <br> Some Other Content')
       .position(pos)
       .hideDelay(3000)
);
```

Any idea ?

Comment: you can use template attribute. I show example on the below.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can do it like that.

```
var displayToast = function(type, msg) {
    $mdToast.show({
        template: '`<br/>`' + msg + '`<br/>`',
        hideDelay: 6000,
        position: 'bottom right'
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do so

```
$mdToast.show({
          hideDelay   : 3000,
          position    : 'top right',
          templateUrl : 'your_template.html'
        });
```

and in your template

```
<div>Field is required <br> Some Other Content</div>
```